# How can I add some data to firestore as per user logged in, as well as how can I create the profile of the user?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a restaurant application with flutter, I want to use firestore as my database and I've already authenticated with firebase with the help of ***Andrea Bizzotto's*** YouTube tutorial of authentication but I'm not able to understand any tutorial or either not able to integerate into the login/signup page for creating a user info  in cloud firestore, can someone give me a way to do this, just give a basic introduction or direction to find a way to complete it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey there you could check out this github project https://github.com/instaflutter/flutter-login-screen-firebase-auth-facebook-login

Answer (score 0):

after you sign up the user with firebase auth if it's successful you should then run this method to update his data.

```
   Future<dynamic> updateUserData(FirebaseUser user, String photoUrl, String displayName) async {
        final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

        DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
            await _db.collection('users').document(user.uid).get();

        DocumentReference ref =  _db.collection('users').document(user.uid);

        if (snapshot.exists) {
          return ref;
        } else {
          return Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
            return tx.set(
              ref,
              {
                'uid': user.uid,
                'email': user.email,
                'name': displayName,
                'photo': photoUrl,
                'lastSeen': DateTime.now()
              },
            );
          }).then((val) => val.length);
        }
      }
```

Comment: doesn't works, may be I'm doing it wrong, I am trying to call by using "then" after the function. can you suggest me more proper way

Comment: Where do you use then? Typically you would have a sign up function that's  using firebase auth and this is the additional info stored in users document. Show me some code.